# Scrollview change background color after changing page

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `scrollView` which is a **UIScrollView** in a `CustomCell` which is a subclass of **UITableViewCell**. I have two different pages in a cell. So, I'm using my `scrollView` in `pagingEnabled`mode.

My question is that can i change my `scrollView` background color after passing second page then set it back to initial color after returning back ?

So far, i tried to use two different **UIScrollView**, then i realized that i can't use `pagingEnabled` mode.

To be more specific, i want my initial screen which width is 360 and height is 70  in blue,and my second screen is green which starts after 360 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the scrollViewDelegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
           CGFloat pageWidth = 360;
           int page = floor(scroll.contentOffset.x / pageWidth) ;

           if (page == 1) { /// second scroll page
               myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
           } else {  ///first scroll page
               myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
           }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    if (page == 0){
    // first page's background color
    }
    else{
    // first page's background color
    }
}
```

Also in the `viewDidLoad` add this :

```
mainScroll.ContentSize = CGSizeMake(320*2, 70);
```